# Discord.py - How can i kick user without ctx or member? - Solution here

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def timecheck():
    tm = time.localtime()
   
    if tm[6] == 6:
        user = await client.fetch_user(id)
        await user.kick(reason='Test')

@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def mainloop():
    asyncio.create_task(timecheck())


mainloop.start()
```

When i try to run bot it gives me error:

AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'kick

I tried to look into discord documentation but the command didn't work, then i tried to search it but i couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix up the `user` and `member` objects! Members can be kicked, because they are, by definition, member of a guild. `User` represents just a normal Discord user, so nothing to kick there. In order to kick a member from a guild without having the objects given by an event-handler, you will need to create them manually like so

```
guild = client.get_guild(<guild-id>)
member = guild.get_user(<user-id>)
```

where the contents inside the `<>` brackets obviously have to be replaced with the real ids.

---

If guilds or members are however not cached by your bot, you will need to fetch them instead

```
guild = await client.fetch_guild(<guild-id>)
member = await guild.fetch_member(<user-id>)
```

---

You can then use this info to kick the member

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def timecheck():
    tm = time.localtime()
   
    if tm[6] == 6:
        guild = await client.fetch_guild(guildID)
        member = await guild.fetch_member(userID)
        await member.kick(reason='Test')

@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def mainloop():
    asyncio.create_task(timecheck())


mainloop.start()
```

If you're not sure that the fetch functions will **always** return the object, you can also check if they aren't `None` to avoid any errors

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def timecheck():
    tm = time.localtime()
   
    if tm[6] == 6:
        guild = await client.fetch_guild(guildID)
        if guild != None:
            member = await guild.fetch_member(userID)
            if member != None:
                await member.kick(reason='Test')

@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def mainloop():
    asyncio.create_task(timecheck())


mainloop.start()
```